# Converting decimal time to hours to plot a 24-hour timeline chart in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, tableau-api, powerbi-desktop, tableau-desktop

hope you're doing well.
I'm a newbie to PowerBI and I'd want to convert the decimal time/date column values into hours of the time to plot the info over a 24-hour timeline. I was able to achieve this in tableau and as it automatically detects the hours and can easily be able to plot the info. I was a bit close in achieving this in powerBI as I converted the date/time column to time and tried plotting but there's huge noise and looks more cluttered as it took every change in seconds/minutes (the bottom snippet). I've attached the snippets for reference, can anyone pls try to help me on this ? [image]

Comment: I gave up asking for sample data.

Comment: Hey @Peter. sorry for not attaching the data. All I'm trying to achieve is to convert hh:mm:ss to hh AM/PM in powerbi

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI it's recommended to split the DateTime column into separate Date and Time columns.  This is both for performance reasons.  Over a year a DateTime column with 1sec granularity can have 30M different values, which is much more data than storing one column with 365 values, and one with 86,400 values.  And so that your Date column can link to a Date Dimension to provide other DateTime hierarchy attributes, like FiscalQuarter, DayOfWeek, etc.

In Power Query select the DateTime column and go to --> Add Column --> Time -- > Time Only.  Then change the data type of the DateTime column to Date.

This also solves your reporting problem as you can simply put the Time column on the X axis.

[image]

If you want a custom format string for the time you can add a calculated column in Power Query like

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "TimeDesc", each DateTime.ToText(#date(2020,1,1)&[Time], [Format="h tt"]))
```

And configure the new column with a "[Sort by Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column?tabs=powerbi-desktop)" of Time.

Comment: thanks for the response. So, I've duplicated the column and changed the type to time. But when I am plotting it on the chart, I see the dates instead of hh AM/PM

Comment: Instead of duplicating, with the column selected On Query Editor, Go to --> Add Column --> Time -- > Time Only

Comment: I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Sorry if I've made it worse. So, I achieved hh AM/PM format in a new Time column. But when I plot this time column onto the chart, the values are so cluttered as I've attached the snippet in the question (bottommost) but can we able to see plain area chart as I did in tableau (attached snippet on the top)

Comment: Maybe it is because, there are many column values displaying 1 am values and 2 am values and so on and they aren't grouped together that could be the reason these each and every similar value is being plotted on the axis, what if we can get the count of all values at 1am, 2 am and so on ?

Comment: Why are there time values on the Y axis?

Comment: As usual: endless discussions when no sample data was shared.